# StrongLoop and Loopback are getting hanged after taking application name

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to creating my first application with loopback js but it's getting hanged after taking the application name.

I tried with both StrongLoop & LoopBack-cli but getting the same issue.

StrongLoop:

[image: StrongLoop]

LoopBack:

[image: LoopBack]

I have gone through the various posts and googling and nothing helps me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long does it stay in this stage? In my old computer it used to take a while to get past this step. I would start this and go do something else and come back after 5 mins to get the next step

Comment: @Sashi I wait for an hour but still same.

Comment: Thats interesting, have you tried running it on Git Bash or Cygwin?

Comment: @Sashi No, I am running it on windows 7.

Comment: Cygwin and Git Bash will both work on Windows 7. Try it on one of them and see if it works faster

Comment: But why it's now working with window 7? Could docker can help me in any ways?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178421/discussion-between-sashi-and-shivang-agarwal).